# Group Sentences into paragraph of similar topics from large dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I have a large text corpus. Need to group sentences into paragraph based on topics in NLP(Python)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can fork and run [this notebook](https://github.com/JNYH/Metis-Project-4-NLP/blob/master/unsupervised_topic_modeling_product.ipynb) which uses both Count Vectorizer and TF-IDF for topic modelling